# divide $x$ people into $y$ groups with each group containing minimum $z$ people

Tags: combinatorics

I have the concrete problem: Given 5 people, divide the people into 2 groups, with a minimum of 2 people in each group.

What I've tried to do:

I have person $a,b,c,d,e$. The order of the group does not matter.
Therefore I simple pair each letter with a different one and then remove the duplicates giving me a total of $4+3+2+1=10$. I'm fairly certain about the result, but I know it is not an effective way of doing it.

I tried looking into combinatorics and looked over a few other topics here on math.stackexchange. From what I gather you could calculate it by $5!/(2!3!2!)$, with the numerator being the total ways of combining the number of people and the denominator being the condition.

I am hoping someone can help to understand if I am correct or wrong and possible explain to me why or simple give me a good link to an article/video explaining the concept.

Comment: nitpick the term is set, group in math, has another meaning.

Comment: So i'm actually trying to solve how many different subsets I can make from the set and the conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are asking *In how many ways can I rearrange a group of five people into two groups with not less than two people in each*? What you are looking for is given by [combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination). There are $\frac{5!}{2!3!} = 10$ ways to do it, since there are exactly $10$ ways to choose a group of $2$ (or $3$ people from a group of $5$, it doesn't matter since $\binom{n}{k} = \binom{n}{n-k}$) and the second group is uniquely determined by the first.

Comment: Exactly! Thank you Hasek. I have a follow up question. Given additional conditions, such as $a$ and $b$ not working together. How would you go about applying that to the concept of combinations?
I still have $5!$ combinations in the numerator. And I still have the condition from before, but I need to eliminate the groups counted with a and b in them. I can count 6 ways, but with a larger set and more conditions it wouldn't work to count it.

Comment: @Christian, I understand what you are asking for, but the term "condition" is rather vague and it can't be done just like a mechanical rule. It is important to understand how these formulas arise. There are $n!$ ways to rearrange $n$ elements in a row where the order makes sense. Then there exist $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$ possibilities to extract ordered list of $k$ elements from these $n$. If you aren't interested in ordered list just divide this expression by $k!$ and obtain already known formula for combinations which don't preserve order. It works similarly for other conditions.

Comment: I thought there was a set rule which could be applied every time. I obviously still do not fully understand the concept. But I have something to look into now. Thanks for the anwers.